# Invalid Character Error With JQuery Ajax Json Feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have JavaScript function to get a Json Feed.

```
function CustomerDetails(CustomerNumber)
{
$.ajax({ 
url: "GetCustomerDetails.php",
type: "GET", 
data:{CustomerNumber:CustomerNumber},
async: true, 
dataType: "json",
success: function(ReturnedData)
    {
    var JsonObj = $.parseJSON(ReturnedData);
    for (var i in JsonObj)
        {
        alert(JsonObj[i].CustName);
        }                   
    }
})
}
```

The GetCustomerDetails.php puts out a Json Feed that looks like this:

```
[{"CustName":"BOB GREEN","CustNum":"1346859"}]
```

When I call the CustomerDetails function, I am getting an "Invalid character" error (m.parseJSON [Line: 4, Col: 15934], jquery-min.js)
The output for the Json feed has no spaces or lines feeds before or after the data.
What I am I doing wrong?

Comment: The request was send? If yes how the response looks (chrome-console> network tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataType: "json",
```

This property on the ajax tells jQuery that the response will be json.  It will automatically parse it before it passes it into the success.  Performing the parse in the success is unnecessary as it will already be parsed.

Optionally you could take that off and do your parse in the success method.  However, if your endpoint is setting the `Content-Type: application/json` on the response, jQuery will try to auto parse it anyway, so it's probably best to just use the dataType option if you know the response should be json.

Comment: Thanks! Skipping the  $.parseJSON(ReturnedData); and then just looping through the data worked.